# change animateLayoutChanges property using java code

Tags: java, android, layout-animation

I'm working on a android application which is use layout change animations. what i want to know is, is there any one know how to change the "andorid:animateLayoutChanges" proberty using java code.

my current value is

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

I want to change it to "true" in activity onResume() method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `setLayoutTransition()` method in your code:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
//or, if previously enabled in xml, use getLayoutTransition()

//enable animation
setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);

//disable animation
setLayoutTransition(null);
```

source: [Animating Layout Changes](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)