# Animating layouts using the "animateLayoutChanges" attribute in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation

I have a `LinearLayout`, for which I apply `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the parent `LinearLayout`. When the user clicks a toggle button, the `LinearLayout` "collapses" (I set the view's visibility as `LinearLayout.GONE` programmatically, and when they click it again, it expands by programmatically setting the visibility back to `LinearLayout.VISIBLE`.

The animation of it collapsing and expanding works correctly.

However, any items below the collapsable/expandable `LinearLayout` snap back to the top before the animation of the collapse is complete. The items that are snapping back are NOT inside the parent which has `animateLayoutChanges` set to `true`, and I don't think there is any way I can put them inside it.

Here is my layout hierarchy (I didn't mention the attributes to keep it short):

```
<!-- Top most LinearLayout-->
<LinearLayout>

    <!-- LinearLayout containing android:animateLayoutChanges="true"-->
    <LinearLayout>

        <!-- RelativeLayout containing button to toggle LinearLayout visibility below-->
        <RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- LinearLayout that has its visibility toggled -->
        <LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This entire layout is inserted programmatically into another `LinearLayout` (see below):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This is where the previous XML layout containing the toggle-able LinearLayout
         is inserted programmatically. -->

    <!-- This button snaps back up to the top before the animation is complete. -->
    <Button />

</LinearLayout>
```

I realize the problem would be solved if I added the `Button` that snaps up to the `LinearLayout` that has `animateLayoutChanges` as true. However, this isn't an options for a few reasons.

So is there any other work around?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `animateLayoutChanges` try adding 
  `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer);` in your onClick method where `transitionsContainer` is parent of views that should be animated.

For example your parent layout is is

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/transitions_container">

    <!--add your widgets here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

And in code

```
final ViewGroup transitionsContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.transitions_container);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer);
        // do your staff with changing children of transitionsContainer           
    }
});
```

Check https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... What if you remove the 'animateLayoutChanges' from the embedded layout, and add it to the parent layout (second XML)? I suspect that this would animate everything. You may have to set the property to true in code since you're programmatically embedding the layout.

Here's how to do it programmatically 
[Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741091/change-animatelayoutchanges-property-using-java-code)

Another option would be to use the .animate property programmatically on the button that snaps back

```
myButton.animate().translationY(floatYposition).setDuration(300); //300 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

for linear layout try to manually enable 'changing' transition too
look at this for frame layout.. try that for your linear layout..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116293/2719243