# AnimateLayoutChanges on margin and width/height only works if another element is appearing/disappearing

Tags: android

I set up a simple activity to try to boil down this problem.
I have a FrameLayout in which I have enabled "AnimateLayoutchanges". 
I have a button which onclick changes the layout margin and width of a TextView.
If this is the only layout change, the change in margin and width will NOT get animated. However, if I simple set the visibility if another child of the same FrameLayout, both the visibility change AND the margin/width change will animate.

Side note: the visibility and margin+width change will happen in sequence as opposed to simultaneously, is there a way to change this behavior?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#888"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activities.TestActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/PivotTheme" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonHandler"
        android:text="test button 1" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple_gradient_end"
            android:text="TestView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testTv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/purple_gradient_end"
            android:text="TestView" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public void buttonHandler(View view){
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) testTv.getLayoutParams();
    if(testDown) {
        params.setMargins(100, 400, 0, 0);
        params.width = 400;
        testTv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);// if I comment out this line, nothing will animate
        testDown = false;
    } else {
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params.width = 100;
        testTv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        testDown = true;
    }
    testTv.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

I feel like this is a bug with android where changes in margin or width are failing to set a flag to trigger animation, but if this flag is set by changing visibility, then all the animations are properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

for that type of changing..like change param..you need to enable 'changing' too (animateLayoutChange must be true)

```
    val frmMain=findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.frmMain)

    val currentTransitions=frmMain.layoutTransition
    currentTransitions.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
    frmMain.layoutTransition=currentTransitions
```